# when does a property with attribute retain gets released?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa

If I am creating a property with attribute retain like this

@property (nonatomic,retain) NSArray *array;

if this property is set by using dot operator or setarray method the retain count of this object will increase. please explain when will this property be released ? or do I have to release it manually.

if I do

self.array = nil;

in dealloc method of a class, will this decrease the retain count ?

Comment: This has been asked so many times. Where exactly did your google research fail?

Answer (score 0):

Whenever a strong pointer that is set to an object is changed to point to nil, it will decrease the reference count.

If you are using ARC, and you have no other strong (or retain) pointers pointing to the same NSArray object, your object will be deallocated as soon as you set your self.array to nil.

Comment: He is clearly not using ARC. But well, he accepted your answer....